# check whether build execution is successful using vb script

Tags: vbscript, cmd, build

I am using VB Script to run a batch file, which will run a build.

After the build , I want to check whether the build was successful or unsuccessful in the script itself, even if the build is successful or unsuccessful.

How can i achieve it?

```
Dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run "cmd /k cd c:\filename.bat"
```

I am just using the above code, which will run a batch file which will run a build, next i want to check whether build was successful or unsuccessful .
So how can i pause my vb script for some time and wait for the build to get completed and know whats the result

Comment: Edit your question and post your code !

Comment: @Hackoo


        Dim objShell
        
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    objShell.Run "cmd /k cd c:\filename.bat"

I am just using the above code, which will run a batch file which will run a build, next i want to check whether build was successful or unsuccessful .
So how can i pause my vb script for some time and wait for the build to get completed and know whats the result

Comment: What kind of build? post its source not in comments but in your question

Answer (score 0):

Give a try for this sample code :

```
Option Explicit
Dim BatchFile,strText
strText = "@echo off & echo Hello World. & TimeOut /T 5 & exit"
BatchFile = "filename.bat"
Call Create_BatchFile(strText,BatchFile)
wscript.echo "We execute the batch file in hidden mode !" & vbcr & "Just clic Ok button to run it !"
Call Run(BatchFile,0,True)
wscript.echo "We execute the batch file in normal mode !" & vbcr & "Just clic Ok button to run it !"
Call Run(BatchFile,1,True) 
'**********************************************************************************************
Function Run(StrCmd,Console,bWaitOnReturn)
    Dim ws,MyCmd,Result
    Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
'A value of 0 to hide the MS-DOS console
    If Console = 0 Then
        MyCmd = "CMD /C " & StrCmd & ""
        Result = ws.run(MyCmd,Console,bWaitOnReturn)
        If Result = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Success"
        Else
            MsgBox "An unknown error has occurred!",16,"An unknown error has occurred!"
        End If
    End If
'A value of 1 to show the MS-DOS console
    If Console = 1 Then
        MyCmd = "CMD /K " & StrCmd & ""
        Result = ws.run(MyCmd,Console,bWaitOnReturn)
        If Result = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Success"
        Else
            MsgBox "An unknown error has occurred!",16,"An unknown error has occurred!"
        End If
    End If
    Run = Result
End Function
'**********************************************************************************************
Sub Create_BatchFile(strText,BatchFile)
Const ForWriting = 2
Dim fso,ts
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile(BatchFile,ForWriting,True)
ts.WriteLine strText
ts.Close
End Sub
'**********************************************************************************************
```

Comment: Ok, Can i read the content of the command prompt without using '>' or '>>' using vbscript . Because i want to read the content some moment later when the batch file get executed completely
@Hackoo

Comment: @AkashS.Did you mean that you want to catch the code source of any batch file is running ? like this one that can catch the source code of any vbscript : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36305046/use-vbscript-to-merge-all-open-instances-of-notepad-exe-and-save-to-txt-file?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: I don't want source code of the batch file running, i want to catch the output of the batch file executed from the command promt.